# Post-build event Powershell script blocks when is not run under Local System account

Tags: powershell, post-build-event

I have an Post-build event that call a Powershell script to do some complex actions. If i run the project locally it's work perfectly. Also it's work on the  current build machine (I use XAML builds).

However now I want to migrate to VSTS. When that project is building, the process freeze with no error. After the timeout time pass I can found in logs this error :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): Warning MSB4220: Waiting for the currently executing task "Exec" to cancel.
```

I am using an on-premises vm where I have installed the VSTS Build Agent. After some investigations I have noticed that changing the "log on as" of the service to "Local System account" it's work. The problem is that I have to run it under a specific account that have some special permissions.

If I am logged with that user and run the project from visual studio it's work fine.

Comment: Can you provide the sample code that can reproduce this issue? On the other hand, try to run the agent as interactive mode https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts#choose-interactive-or-service-mode

Comment: I don't know what code produce this issue. The post-build event that cause it is: powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass $(ProjectDir)Build.ps1 ...(arguments)... The script from Build.ps1 it is complex and it call some jar files. I don't know the functionality of those jar files, because they are some third party stuffs. I tried to run the agent on interactive mode, but with no success.

Comment: What's the result if you try it with the simple code in Build.ps1?

Comment: That was a good idea. I removed all the code from Build.ps1 and let only a Write-Host, and the problem is still happening.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue (agent log on as my account). What special permissionis the user has? What's the result if you change the log on as account to your account?

Comment: Before the build step, I have some custom activities, witch get stuff from some TFS servers (where that user have access) and also copy/paste different files to a shared path. Hmm It is possible that my user to don't have some rights that are needed by the agent to build?

Comment: What's result if build the project through MSBuild command? (Log on agent machine with that user account)

Comment: I tried to build it with Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 and it get stuck in the same place ( with and without "run as administrator"). If I build it on VS 2017 it works. At leas now I know is not a problem from VSTS. Thanks you a lot.

Comment: How about do that through VSTS build task directly? (run post build script through command line or powershell task)

Comment: Yes, I think it might be a good workaround. I still have to investigate if the output from that post-build event is needed at build time, or I can do it after the build.